# How do I set up selenium based tests in C# in visual studio?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to testing using selenium. I want to know how I can create a test in visual studio which tests if the user navigates to a webpage. What packages/dependencies do I need? what sort of project file do I need to open in visual studio i.e normal project in .NET or xUnit testing project etc. I am using a MAC.

below is something I tried to create but for some reason it did not work. Am I doing something wrong? I clicked on build and it said successful. Then I clicked on run but the test didnt do anything.

[image: imageDescription]

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace test
{
    [TestFixture()]
    public class Test
    {



        [Test()]
        public void TestCase()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("/Users/andrew/Desktop/test/chromedriver");

            //Navigate to google page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:www.google.com");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what does not work exactly. "for some reason it did not work" is very broad. If the Test Explorer is not finding the tests then you may need to install the Extension for the test runner. In your case it's NUnit Test Runner based on the screenshot.

Comment: Because you need to run the test.  From the menu: 'Run' -> 'Run Unit Tests' or Cmd+T